# Convert minutes to HH24:MI format

Tags: oracle, time

Can you please help in converting minutes to the format of ('HH24:MI').

I am getting the result in integer which is the minutes. So, how to convert them?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming, you want to convert 492 minutes:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + 492/24/60, 'hh24:mi') from dual;
```

If you want a function:

```
create or replace 
  function tq84_convert_minutes_hh24mm (p_minutes in number) 
  return varchar2 is
begin

    return to_char (trunc(sysdate) + p_minutes / 24/60, 'hh24:mi');

end tq84_convert_minutes_hh24mm;
/
```

Later ...

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line (tq84_convert_minutes_hh24mm(492));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
WITH c AS
  (SELECT 492 AS MINUTES FROM DUAL)
SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MINUTES / 60), '09')) || ':' ||
       TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(ABS(MINUTES), 60)), '09')) AS HHMM
  FROM C
```

This will have issues if the time exceeds 1440 minutes (24 hours) but it gives you something to start with.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This can save you, but I had problems with time greater than 1440 minutes.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + [MINUTES]/24/60, 'hh24:mi') from dual;
```

So I did a function that verifies if minute is greater or equal 1440:

```
IF (QT_MINUTES_P IS NOT NULL) THEN
   IF (QT_MINUTES_P >= 1440) THEN
         SELECT  ROUND(QT_MINUTES_P/ 60) ||':'|| MOD(QT_MINUTES_P, 60)
         INTO    DS_RESULT
         FROM    DUAL;
     ELSE
       SELECT   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (QT_MINUTES_P)/24/60, 'hh24:mi')
         INTO   DS_RESULT
         FROM   DUAL;
   END IF;
END IF;
```