# Convert minutes into amount of working days, hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

The result of an oracle sql query gives me a column with the total amount in minutes.

How can I convert this into a result that gives me the amount of working days, hours and minutes?

A working day contains 10 hours (600 minutes)

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931574/convert-minutes-to-hh24mi-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math.

```
SELECT trunc(minutes/600)||' working days, '||trunc(mod(minutes,600)/60)||' working hours and '||mod(minutes,60)||' minutes'
FROM (SELECT 1000 as minutes FROM dual)
```