# Converting Integer into time

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 12c version.
I have a column which is integer data type and it represents total minutes.
I need to convert it into HOURS:MINUTES format.

Could someone suggest how to do that?

Thanks,
Venu

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45719693/edit) to include sample data, expected results, and what you've already tried (and what was wrong with it). What data type is the result supposed to be? Can the time exceed 24 hours, and if so what should happen?

Comment: Also [probably a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11931574/266304).

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly easy thing to accomplish using a series of built in functions.

```
to_char(floor(field / 60) || ':' || to_char(mod(field, 60), 'FM00')
```

**Breaking it down**:

1. Get the number of hours: `to_char(floor(field / 60)`

   - `field / 60` gets us the number of hours
   - `floor()` ensures that we don't have to deal with decimals
   - `to_char()` converts it to a string so we can concatenate it.
2. Add the ':' `|| ':' ||`
3. Get the number of minutes

   - `mod(field, 60)` gets the remainder of `field / 60`
   - `to_char()` again converts to a string for the concat step
   - `'FM00'` ensures that we keep our leading zeros.

Obviously, you'll need to replace `field` with whatever the field in your database is called.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. Its working fine now.

Comment: @VenugopalSeetharaman: If this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **to_date** built-in function to translate the integer into a valid time.

Example

```
SQL> select to_char ( to_date ( '2300', 'HH24MI'), 'HH:MI AM') integer_time from dual;
```

Comment: It works only up to 12 hours, I don't think AM/PM is required.