# Dealing with time in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

---

I am creating a database that students can use to check the availability of tutors, and schedule appointments with them. I will be doing the GUI and triggers outside of this example.

My issue is I have a table, Tutor, that includes the tutor information as well as the times that they are available. When I declare the datatype *time* during table creation it is not recognizing it as a valid datatype.

I would like to store each tutors available times for each day to reference later on in a scheduling table (function will check if the tutor is available on that day, during that time period to allow update on schedule table). Also each tutor can only work a given number of hours. These issues are besides the point but may conflict with the datatype given, and give reason to why I am using time.

I am using pl/sql and oracle sql developer.

Any insight is appreciated, I have included my code below, see table 'schedule' for the aforementioned information

```
----Dropping tables----
drop table student cascade constraints;
drop table course cascade constraints;
drop table schedule cascade constraints;
drop table tutor cascade constraints;

 ----Creating Tables-----
 create table course(
 cou_id number(4),
 major_id number(4),
 cou_name varchar2(20),
 major_name varchar2 (20),
 professor varchar2 (20),
 constraint course_pk primary key (cou_id)
 );


 create table student(
 stu_id number(4) constraint stu_id_pk primary key,
 stu_fn varchar2 (20),
 stu_ln varchar2 (20),
 stu_city varchar2 (20),
 stu_ethn varchar2 (20),
 cou_id number(4) constraint cou_id_fk references course(cou_id),
 stu_gpa number(3,2) constraint stu_gpa_c1 check (stu_gpa <=4.0 and stu_gpa >=0)
 );

 create table tutor(
 tutor_id number(4) constraint tutor_id_pk primary key,
 tut_fn varchar2 (20),
 tut_ln varchar2 (2),
 major_id number(4) constraint tutor_major_id_fk references course(major_id),
 mon_avail time,
 tues_avail time,
 wed_avail time,
 thurs_avail time,
 fri_avail time
 );

 create table schedule(
 schedule_id number(4) constraint schedule_id primary key,
 tut_id  number(4) constraint tut_id_fk references tutor(tutor_id),
 stu_id number(4) constraint stu_id_fk references student(stu_id),
 day_resv varchar(2) constraint day_resv_c1 check(day_resv=upper(day_resv))
                     constraint day_resv_c2 check (day_resv in ('MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR')),
 time_resv time
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not have a TIME datatype. The DATE type has fields for both date (year, month, day) and time (hours, minutes, integer seconds). If you need more precision you can use TIMESTAMP, with allows fractional seconds to be measured. For your purposes DATE is probably what you want. [Manual reference here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413)

Best ofluck.

Comment: wow I am surprised that they do not have a time datatype!! I'll try using date and see if that works. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Given that (as @bob-jarvis pointed out in his answer) Oracle does not have a TIME datatype, you may wish to consider using SMALLINT fields for the times, and store in them as minutes (after midnight) value.

This will make most of the comparisons fast and easy, with only formatting into `HH:MM` for display being harder, and this page should help with that: [Convert minutes to HH24:MI format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931574/convert-minutes-to-hh24mi-format)

Note that you will be converting a number, not a date-time so look at @bobs's answer there for the correct example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be the [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i78291) data type. As the name implies it stores days, hours, minutes, seconds and fractional seconds and might be easier ti handle than "integer minutes".