# Find date and hour - of interval data oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with a date column that represents the minutes from 01-01-1988
and a minutes columns

I need to represent the real data and the hour
for example -
date - 18544320
hour 510

I tried for the date field with -

```
select to_date('01-01-1988 00:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') + interval '18544320' minute(9) 
from dual;
```

It works,
But when I try it with the column itself it doesn't work:

```
select to_date('01-01-1988 00:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') + interval W.CURDATE minute (9) 
from TABULA.MAC_WORKERASSIGNATIO W;
```

923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Any idea ?

Comment: I must admit that I have never understood, why people store a number that represents some datetime offset rather than just simply storing the actual datetime. But well, you should be able to calculate the minutes interval by multiplying one minute: `... + (w.curdate * interval '1' minute)`.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree...

Comment: Do you know how to represent the hour ? - column of hour shows 510 - which is minutes from 00:00 - hour should be 8:30 AM

Comment: That is weird. `date '1988-01-01' + (w.curdate * interval '1' minute)` results in a datetime (that Oracle calls DATE inappropriately). What tool are you using to display this datetime? Check the tool's settings. Most common is something along the lines of 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'. I don't even know of any setting that would display the time part with three-digit minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I try it with the column itself it doesn't work

As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B), interval literals are just that - literal values like `interval '18544320' minute`. You cannot use a column or variable because by definition that would no longer be a *literal* value.

As the documentation also says:

> If you have date data in numeric form, then you can use the NUMTOYMINTERVAL or NUMTODSINTERVAL conversion function to convert the numeric data into interval values.

... as @SelVazi has shown.

You can also multiply a fixed interval to get the result you want:

select date '1988-01-01'

- W.CURDATE * interval '1' minute
  from MAC_WORKERASSIGNATIO W;

Anecdotally there can be a noticeable performance difference between the functions and multiplied literals, but it may depend on your version and other things, and may not be significant for your data volumes. It may be worth comparing both to see if one is better for you than the other.

I've used a date literal as well, which is shorter than using `to_date()` and represents midnight on that date. Even if you use `to_date()` you can shorten your code by removing the time parts, as those will still default to midnight.

> Do you know how to represent the hour ? - column of hour shows 510 - which is minutes from 00:00 - hour should be 8:30 AM

You seem to be storing the number of days between an 1988-01-01 epoch and midnight on a date in one column, and then the time for that date in a separate column - both stored as the number of minutes.

You can use the same calculation for both columns and just add them together, either before or after multiplying by an interval of a single minute:

```
select date '1988-01-01'
  + W.CURDATE * interval '1' minute
  + W.HOUR * interval '1' minute
from MAC_WORKERASSIGNATIO W;
```

| DATE'1988-01-01'+W.CURDATE*INTERVAL'1'MINUTE+W.HOUR*INTERVAL'1'MINUTE |
| --- |
| 2023-04-05 08:30:00 |

```
select date '1988-01-01'
  + (W.CURDATE + W.HOUR) * interval '1' minute
from MAC_WORKERASSIGNATIO W;
```

| DATE'1988-01-01'+(W.CURDATE+W.HOUR)*INTERVAL'1'MINUTE |
| --- |
| 2023-04-05 08:30:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YO3T4M2k)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`numToDSInterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html#GUID-5A7392A8-7976-4465-8839-A65EFF1A80B6) function :

```
select to_date('01-01-1988 00:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') + numToDSInterval( W.CURDATE, 'minute' )
from TABULA.MAC_WORKERASSIGNATIO W;
```

Comment: Do you know how to represent the hour ? - column of hour shows 510 - which is minutes from 00:00 - hour should be 8:30 AM

Comment: Glad to hear :) .. This can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931574/convert-minutes-to-hh24mi-format

Comment: Check here : https://dbfiddle.uk/qVrjIwNp